# Which NoSQL solution for a dating search site?

Tags: nosql

I am highly interested in new NoSQL solutions to implement a search engine for a dating site. However because of having a lot of possibilities, I am little bid confused. My requirements,

1) 10 million people
2) More than 8 index (gender, online, city, name etc...)
3) Scalability

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You wanna go for either mangoDB or CouchDB.
CouchDB scales a little better while mangoDB syntax is a little more familiar.

also it depends what framework/language u use to create the dating site.

i personally would choose couchdb. (u should know javascript...a lot)

Comment: @Mike Sherov:  Yes, but tastier.

Comment: @Bill, I also prefer sofaDB to couchDB. It doesn't require as much javascript knowledge as couchDB.

Comment: I posted a blog on April 1 about *Hammock*, a NoSQL data store that's hard to get into and hard to get out of.  http://karwin.blogspot.com/2010/04/announcing-awk-on-rails.html

Answer (score 3):

[Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) is a data store and fulltext search engine that might be useful to you.  Solr is [rarely mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339793/why-are-document-stores-like-lucene-solr-not-included-in-nosql-conversations/) as a NoSQL technology, but it shares many characteristics with document-oriented databases.

Keep in mind that you have to know what type of queries you're going to run before you can choose a NoSQL solution or design your database.

That's in contrast to a relational database, where you can design a general-purpose database based on the data relationships.

Answer (score 2):

With that large of a dataset you would probably be well advised to look at search as separate from data store.  As someone suggested, SOLR will index your data for you to search independently of your database.  You have 2 problems, data store and search.

Answer (score 0):

ElasticSearch http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/
Can handle age difference, geographic location, tastes and dislikes, etc. Or a leaderboard system that depends on many variables.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want something that has sophisticated search and aggregation support.
Elasticsearch is a good candidate.  In addition to its ability to perform fuzzy, proximity searches (which is something you'd likely want), you'd also want to integrate some machine learning pipeline to constantly improve your matching 'accuracy'.