# How Apache Solr is No-SQL when it also uses schema.xml

Tags: mysql, solr, rdbms, solrcloud

No-SQL databases are schemaless as per the definition.But Apache Solr needs schema to be configured before indexing data.So, How Apache Solr is NoSQL and different from traditional RDBMS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are document stores like Lucene / Solr not included in NoSQL conversations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339793/why-are-document-stores-like-lucene-solr-not-included-in-nosql-conversations)

Answer (score 0):

I would not term a search engine like Solr/Lucene as a NoSQL database.
Traditional NoSQL databases are MongoDB (Document DB), DynamoDB, Cassandra (Wide column store), HBase, Redis etc.

Although for another viewpoint see here https://lucidworks.com/2010/04/30/nosql-lucene-and-solr/

Answer (score 0):

It's not true that NoSQL are schemaless by definition.

Have you seen https://json-schema.org ?

Even MongoDB supports [schema validation features](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) since version 3.6.

Comment: But when we say "A NoSQL database lets you build an application without having to define the schema first unlike relational databases ". How this statement is correct?

Comment: In MongoDB, using a schema is optional. You may create a collection without defining a schema and begin adding documents to it. In SQL, you must define the structure of a table with columns and data types first. You can't insert into a table that doesn't exist, and a table cannot exist without a defined structure.

Comment: You should try using MongoDB. There are many books and tutorials available. Experiencing it for even a few hours will do more to explain how it works than I can explain in a Stack Overflow comment.